# struts, hibernate, mysql - char encoding problem

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, character-encoding, struts

I have a web app that gathers some data from the user and saves them to a mysql database. The problem is that for a String like "Ajánlat kiküldése", what gets stored to the database is "AjÃ¡nlat kikÃ¼ldÃ©se".

For my database, i have DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8. For my tables i have DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8.

In my hibernate.cfg.xml i have:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
```

If I enter "Ajánlat kiküldése" directly into the database using a mysql client, the text gets stored correctly. SO somewhere along the way inside my application the text gets changed.

I have this in my jspx page:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
```

For my form I use sutrts html taglib and the code is very simple:

```
<html:form action="/submitAddProject">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>
                        <html:text property="projectNameToAdd"/> 
                    <td>
                 etc.
```

On submit, when I do myForm.getProjectNameToAdd, I have a different text than the one I enter in the form. (AjÃ¡nlat kikÃ¼ldÃ©se  instead of Ajánlat kiküldése )

Comment: One more thing: when I enter the text manually in the database, it gets displayed correctly in my application. The problem appears only when saving the text.

Comment: And before I do the saving to the db, when I call a getter on my String field that makes problems, I already get the text in the wrong encoding. So it appears that the problem is not when I try to save to db, but when the fields of my form object are being populated from the html page, more exactly, the string received by the stter is already twisted and different from the string entered in the text field.

Comment: are you using any connection pooling framewrok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create the following filter:

```
public class Utf8EncodingFilter implements Filter {

 public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}

 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next)
 throws IOException, ServletException {
  request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
  next.doFilter(request, response);
 }

 public void destroy(){}
}
```

UPDATE:
You need to create Utf8EncodingFilter class, import Filter interface, exception, etc. (any modern IDE will do this for you). Then you need to add this filter into your deployment descriptor (can be found at WEB-INF/web.xml) using the following syntax:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>UTF-8 Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.Utf8EncodingFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UTF-8 Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

You can read more about filters here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pj2ee10.html

Comment: Sry but how should I use this class? Where to put it ? :) In struts, there is a servlet called controller I think, that calls reset and setters for my form object. When the setter is called, it already receives a wrong char encoding. So, form has good data, setter receives bad data. Somewhere along the way someone twists the data.

Comment: You need to create Utf8EncodingFilter class, import Filter interface, exception, etc. (any modern IDE will do this for you). Then you need to add this filter into your deployment descriptor (can be found at WEB-INF/web.xml) using the following syntax:

Comment: So every web application that wants to use strange chars has to do this thing with the filter?

Comment: Sorry for this, couldn't insert syntax, so just updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, this filter helped me to fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried lots of possible solutions. This was the only thing to help.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but my problem was directly with hibernate saving the data in MySQL. The problem can be easily fixed by appending useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 to your connection string in configuration file.

For example: jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myHibernateDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Worked for me like a piece of magic.

This is the article that talks about it: http://www.isocra.com/2007/01/utf-8-with-hibernate-30-and-mysql/